# How to I create a column in a Dataframe I need to have 1 if in the range and 0 if otherwise?

Tags: python

According to this strategy, we should invest between November and April and don't invest between May and October. Add a column `month` to the DataFrame `world_returns` with the calendar month of each observation. For every row, in this column, you should have a number from 1 to 12 indicating to which calendar month that observation belongs. Add a second column called `signal` that is equal to `1` if the month is between November and April (included) and `0` otherwise.

Can someone please help with the second part of the question for the column 'signal'

As of now i have put:

world_returns['month'] = world_returns.index.month

world_returns['signal'] = np.where(world_returns['month'] ==(11,12,1,2,3,4) ,1 ,0)

world_returns.head()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with what you have tried is you are trying to check where the month column contains the **whole** tuple `(11,12,1,2,3,4)`, rather than checking where the values in month are in that tuple. Your code would work if your dataframe looked like below:

```
  data                 month
0  foo                     1
1  foo                     2
2  foo  (11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Then `np.where(df['month'] == (11,12,1,2,3,4) ,1 ,0)` returns `array([0, 0, 1])`.

What you want to do is have a 1 if the month is in (11,12,1,2,3,4). To do this, you need to edit your conditional statement within the where clause.  The function [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) can be used to check if a value is contained within a list, like the below:

```
world_returns['month'].isin([11,12,1,2,3,4])
```

If you change your conditional statement in the where clause, you should get the desired result.